# How to change point color of forest plot in metafor()

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I have a forest plot constructed using metafor::forestplot() and I'd like to color the points and CIs based on a grouping variable that has two levels (dat$target_status = 'targeted' or 'nontargeted'). Passing the colors through a vector and into forest() 'col' did not work for me. The following code changes the summary polygon, but not the points and whiskers:

```
cols <- c("red", "blue")[match(dat$target_status, c("targeted", "nontargeted"))]

forest(res.overall, xlim=c(-8, 6), #at=log(c(0.05, 0.25, 1, 4)), #atransf=exp,
       #ilab=cbind(dat$tpos, dat$tneg, dat$cpos, dat$cneg),
       #ilab.xpos=c(-9.5,-8,-6,-4.5), 
       cex=0.75, 
       ylim=c(-3, 53),
       order=order(factor(dat$region4, level=c("south","north islands", "central","north")),dat$target_status, dat$yi), 
       rows=c(4:11,17:22,28:35,41:47),
       mlab=mlabfun("biomass overall", res.overall),
       slab=paste(dat$group),
       col=cols,
       #showweights = TRUE,
       #psize=1.3, 
       header="Region | Monitoring Group")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `colout` argument. See the documentation:

https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/forest.rma.html